# Tkinter memory game

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a memory game using Tkinter, as the title states. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import random

difficulty = 16
rowsize= 4
columnsize = 4
numcount = 0
lastnum = 0
gotitcorrect = False
textInGrid = ''

root = Tk()
root.title("MEMORY GAME!!")
root.configure(bg='gray')

def GameStart():
    menuFrame.pack_forget()
    gameFrame.pack()

def Timer(tim):
    time.sleep(tim)

def GetRandomNumber():
    lst1 = [i for i in range(1,9)]
    lst2 = [i for i in range(1,9)]
    random.shuffle(lst1),random.shuffle(lst2)
    numlst = lst1+lst2
    return numlst

numlst = GetRandomNumber()
print(numlst)

for number in numlst:
    def WrongOrRight():
        global numcount, lastnum, gotitcorrect,textInGrid
        if numcount == 0:
            lastnum = number
            numcount+=1
            textInGrid = str(number)
        elif numcount == 1:
            if number == lastnum:
                gotitcorrect = True
                textInGrid=str(number)
            else:
                gotitcorrect = False
                textInGrid=''
            numcount -= 1

menuFrame = Frame(root, bg='gray')
menu = [Label(menuFrame,text='MEMORY GAME', bg = 'gray'), Button(menuFrame,command = GameStart,text = 'Start', bg='gray')]
for i in menu:
    i.pack()
menuFrame.pack()
gameFrame = Frame(root, bg='gray')
cards = [[Button(gameFrame) for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
index = 1
card_dict = {}
for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        # print(index)
        print(numlst[index-1])
        cards[x][y].grid(row = y, column = x, padx=20,pady=20)
        cards[x][y].configure(text = str(numlst[index-1]))
        cards[x][y].configure(command = WrongOrRight)
        card_dict[cards[x][y]] = numlst[index-1]
        index+=1
Timer(5)
for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        cards[x][y].configure(text = '')

for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        cards[x][y].configure(text = textInGrid)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(rowsize,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(columnsize,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

It doesn't give any errors and nothing seems wrong about it but when I run it this is what it gives:

print statements:

> [2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 7, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 6, 2] 2 1 4 6 5 3 7 8 7 4 5
> 8 3 1 6 2

Tkinter window:

[image: start menu]

and when I click the button Start

[image: empty buttons]

For some reason, the buttons are empty. How do I solve this? Also, what are some tips when making a memory game in general?

Answer (score 0):

The button are empty because you are clearing the text - twice.

Remove these loops:

```
for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        cards[x][y].configure(text = '')

for x in range(rowsize):
    for y in range(columnsize):
        cards[x][y].configure(text = textInGrid)
```

For the memory game, shouldn't the buttons be blank by default? The numbers should only appear when the user clicks on the button.